# Ruby 2.5.0 $stdin.getc does not work on consecutive calls

Tags: ruby

I am facing a weird issue with `$stdin.getc` in Ruby 2.5.0 (specifically: ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux])

It seems like there the `getc` method, stores the Enter key also in its buffer, and feeds it to the consecutive `getc` call.

This script demonstrates it:

```
puts "This script uses getc 3 times:"

print "a = "; a = $stdin.getc
print "b = "; b = $stdin.getc
print "c = "; c = $stdin.getc

p "a: #{a}, b: #{b}, c: #{c}"
```

This is the output (I am inputting 1 then 2)

```
This script uses getc 3 times:
a = 1
b = c = 2
"a: 1, b: \n, c: 2"
```

And this is a screencast of the output
https://asciinema.org/a/CFis8pddwZ3ERIA8Np7CCl4wb

Any idea what is going on? Is it a bug?

Comment: `getc` works as expected. The problem is that your terminal provides an editing buffer: try to enter `1`, `backspace`, `2` and `return` and you'll see that `getc` only returns `"2"` and `"\n"`. This is called _cooked_ mode. You have to put your terminal into _raw_ mode to get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, and this behaviour has remained unchanged since ruby `v1.9.1`.

`IO#getc` reads one character from the given IO stream. When you enter `"1"`, then press `<Enter>`, you are actually supplying an input of: `"1\n"`. Therefore, it is *correct* behaviour for your script to read `"\n"` as the second input character.

I think this is what you want to use instead:

```
puts "This script uses gets.chomp 3 times:"

# Note: `String#chomp` removes the trailing newline
print "a = "; a = gets.chomp
print "b = "; b = gets.chomp
print "c = "; c = gets.chomp

p "a: #{a}, b: #{b}, c: #{c}"

## Running the script:
> This script uses gets.chomp 3 times:
> a = 1
> b = 2
> c = 3
> "a: 1, b: 2, c: 3"
```

Comment: This was a weird one.... My script used `$stdin.getch` instead of `getc`. `getch` is only available in ruby 2.4.2, and worked exactly as expected (it ignored the Enter). I switched to using `gets` instead, and checking its first character instead. - and your version with the `.chomp` does not work for me - it gives the same result.

Comment: Oh - sorry, I thought you used `getc.chomp` - just noticed later it is `gets`, thanks.

Comment: Only available in 2.4.2, you say? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-getch ... Works for me!! Note that you must `require 'io/console'` - but again, this has been unchanged for a loooong time.

Comment: Not sure how `getch` is working for a long time.... My travis test matrix says otherwise: https://travis-ci.org/DannyBen/rspec_fixtures/builds/333645582 - i have a test there to does `expect($stdin).to respond_to :getch` and only ruby 2.4.2 passes - Maybe only 2.4.2 did NOT require me to require `io/console`, but there is definitely a change in behavior.

Comment: Maybe *something else* in your code base used to `require 'io/console'`, prior to `2.5`?? I don't particularly fancy [digging though your project dependencies](https://github.com/DannyBen/rspec_fixtures/blob/master/rspec_fixtures.gemspec) to determine the root cause; but from what I can see the language behaviour has not changed.

Comment: No need to dig through anything, its solved, but still weird - something probably brought `io/console` just in ruby 2.4.2 and not in earlier or later versions. Which is weird...